# Double Arrows in igraph and legible lettering

Tags: r, plot, igraph, arrows

```
#Dataframe 
Netzwerkgraph <- graph.data.frame(Datensatz[,1:3], directed = TRUE)

#vectors
actors<-Datensatz$Von
relations<-Datensatz$Nach
weight<-Datensatz$Nachrichten

plot(Netzwerkgraph,vertex.color="lightblue", edge.arrow.size=0.5, edge.lty=1,arrow.mode=3, edge.label=weight, edge.label.cex=0.4)
```

Network Analysis: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEVCi.png)

I would like to avoid the double arrows at the end of some edges. I would like to see, instead, two different edges. Also I want the labeling of the arrows to be legible and not overlapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the argument  `edge.curved` in your plot statement.  You do not provide any data, so I will just generate some random graph to illustrate.

```
library(igraph)

set.seed(76)
g = erdos.renyi.game(10, 0.25, directed=T)

Curve = rep(0, ecount(g))
Curve[which(duplicated(rbind(ends(g, E(g)), 
                ends(g, E(g))[,2:1]))) - 
                ecount(g)] = 0.4
plot(g, edge.curved = Curve)
```

[image: Graph with some edges curved]

The slightly complicated definition of `Curve` has a simple intention. If there is an edge from A to B but not B to A, make Curve = 0 to get a straight edge. If there is an edge in both directions, make Curve be 0.4

This is better, but with the nodes placed just anywhere, the edges are still a little hard to see. You can use `tkplot` to plot the graph and move the nodes to make the graph look nice,  then capture the layout using `tkplot.getcoords` and plot again using the nicer layout. For this graph I got:

```
TKP = tkplot(g, edge.curved = Curve, vertex.color="orange")
LO = tkplot.getcoords(TKP)
plot(g, edge.curved = Curve, layout=LO)
```

[image: Same graph with a better layout]